# JavaScript: change a variable with a prototype function inside the constructor

Tags: javascript, class, variables, prototype

i'm new to "classes" in JavaScript so i hope i've used the right terms in my question.

I tought the this.Variables in the Constructor could be used through all the functions defined with prototype. 
This seems right in one direction but i'm not able to update the variable from within a function.

Here is a little jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/2g4vnL9b/

```
var littleTest = function() {
  this.testVar = "blub";
}
littleTest.prototype = {
  changeTestVar: function(val) {
    this.testVar = val;
  },
  changeTestVar2: function(val) {
    return val;
  }
}

var myTest = new littleTest();
console.log(myTest.testVar); // -> blub

myTest.changeTestVar = "foo";
console.log(myTest.testVar); // -> blub

myTest.testVar = myTest.changeTestVar2("foo");
console.log(myTest.testVar); // -> foo
```

i'm trying to update the this.testVar from the function test.changeTestVar, but it isn't saved inside the object for later use. Only if i set it directly it is saved. 
Can somebody explain me why my code behaves like it behaves and what i have to change?

thank you very much

Comment: I think this line is wrong `myTest.changeTestVar = "foo";` Probably you mean `myTest.changeTestVar("foo");` ?

Comment: In `changeTestVar2` you are not setting `this.testVar2` you are just returning what is passed in

Comment: Notice, that after getting this to work, setting `this.testVar` in the method creates an own property to the instance called the method. `testVar` in the prototype keeps its value, and when you create new instances of `littleTest`, `testVar` in those instances will be `"blub"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ChangeTestVar` is a function, and it's written in different case

```
var myTest = new littleTest();
console.log(myTest.testVar); // -> blub

myTest.changeTestVar("foo");
console.log(myTest.testVar); // -> foo
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/2g4vnL9b/2/)

Comment: after i've read my question again i felt so stupid... it needs 10 minutes that i can mark your answer as my answer, thank you

Comment: No problem, we all make silly and strange mistakes from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `changeTestVar` as a function, not overwrite it with a new value.

Try the following:

```
myTest.changeTestVar("foo");
console.log(myTest.testVar);
```

Also, `changeTestVar2` doesn't change `this` variables at all, it just returns the value passed in.  That's normally called an "identity" function, but it doesn't have any persisting effect on your object.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you code won't work is because your overwriting your prototype functions

```
myTest.changeTestVar = "foo"; //this is replacing the function for a string
console.log(myTest.testVar); // -> blub
```

since your calling a function the value should be passed like any other fucntion

```
myTest.changeTestVar("foo");
console.log(myTest.testVar); // -> foo
```

Answer (score 0):

you were wrong when passing the parameter to the function, by the way you can change the variable directly

```
var myTest = new littleTest();
console.log(myTest.testVar);

myTest.testVar="foo";
console.log(myTest.testVar);
```